# How to run a macro when data is added to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a macro when data is added to a cell.

I found advice on how to run a macro when data is changed in a cell. This won't work. If data is removed from a cell I don't want the macro to run.

I tried an intersect function. I can only make my code run macros when the cells change as opposed to when data is added.

This is my current code:

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'detect data in cell
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J13:J27")) Is Nothing Then
        Call Copy_Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not test if the cell is empty, therefore it's either not updated or it's deleted, and skip the rest of the code if that is the case?

Answer (score 1):

There is no other event that you can use, the `Change`-event is the right place to go. All you need to do is to check if the modified cell(s) contain something or not.

Now when the change-event is triggered, more than one cell can be modified (eg by Cu&Paste), so you will likely need to check all modified cells individually.

As you don't show the code of `Copy_Cell`, I can only assume that this routine is copying something - likely using `ActiveCell`. You should change that routine and let it receive the cell to be copied as parameter.

Also, you need to be aware that if `Copy_Cell` is writing something in the *same* worksheet, the `Change`-Trigger is called recursively. To avoid that, use `Application.EnableEvents = False`.

Your code could look like this:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Change_exit ' Ensure that Events are enabled even if an error occurs
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Target
        If Not Intersect(cell, Range("J13:J27")) Is Nothing And Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            copy_Cell cell
        End If
    Next cell

Change_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. the Copy cell macro runs in a different workbook so that isn't an issue. also, the cell being copied changes based on what line is being written in, so i can't directly specify a cell (i assume that's what you meant?)

Comment: I ment to change the copy cell macro and let if receive a parameter: `Sub Copy_Cell(cell As Range)` and then call it like stated above.